# r: dplyr function to make long format with multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to take this code and turn it into a function:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% select(hp, disp) %>% 
summarise_all(funs(n=sum(!is.na(.)), mean=mean(.,na.rm=T))) %>% 
gather(variable, value, -gear) %>% 
arrange(gear, sub('_.*', '', variable), sub('.*_', '', variable)) %>%
separate(variable, into = c('var', 'metric'), '_')
```

What it does is create a dataframe that I can easily import into Excel and create pivots with. I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
mean_func <- function(vars,groups) {
  results <- test %>% group_by_at(vars(one_of(groups))) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with(vars)), funs(n=sum(!is.na(.)), mean=mean(.,na.rm=T))) %>% 
    gather_(variable, value, -groups) %>% 
    arrange_(groups) %>%
    separate_(variable, into = c('var', 'metric'), '_'); View(results)
}
```

Seems like the problem is somewhere along the `gather` statement, but I'm not sure what could be wrong here. Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems so backwards. Why would you go through the trouble of getting data into R only to export it to make pivot tables with? Whatever the case, programming with dplyr/tidyr verbs has changed. See: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Because the user audience wants the pivot tables so they can easily manipulate and explore the data. It's not my call, or I'd just make plots of everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bit of `tidy` cleanup to change the grouping variable and use group_by_ for programming.

```
library(tidyverse)

mean_func <- function(vars, groups) {
    groups = enquo(groups)

    vars %>% 
        group_by_(groups) %>% 
        dplyr::select(hp, disp) %>% 
        summarise_all(funs(n=sum(!is.na(.)), mean=mean(.,na.rm=T))) %>%
        gather(variable, value, -!!groups) %>%
        arrange(!!groups, sub('_.*', '', variable), sub('.*_', '', variable)) %>%
        separate(variable, into = c('var', 'metric'), '_')
}
mean_func(mtcars, gear)
```